Cannot find module when trying to import CSS file during Jest test
I'm having some issues when it comes to importing css from other css classes when it comes to running the jest tests.
In my LWC I have the base css class, where I have this line @import "c/stepCSS" (where stepCSS is another LWC component as a css)
This has been working fine, until I tried starting to run jest tests with this, but I'm getting this error message now
Cannot find module 'c/stepCSS' from 'force-app/main/default/lwc/baseStep/baseStep.css'

I'm not sure if there's something in particular wrong with this - (c/stepCSS is used in multiple css classes)

Might want to edit your question's title to add "during a Jest test"? Also, please add your jest configuration (the jest.config.js file) and the JS config (jsconfig.json file).

I ended up just ignoring the css files - credit to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48286678/css-module-import-fails-the-jest-test-suit
Went the route of adding a CSSstub to the jest.config.js
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '\\.(css)$': '<rootDir>/force-app/main/default/lwc/utilities/__mocks__/CSSStub.js',
    }

